# SQL query to get sum of headcount according to column grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

The below query is used to find out the headcount of employees in a particular department. This is working fine-

```
 SELECT distinct --LVL2_ORG,
            division, 
           district, 
           department, 
           Count(DISTINCT person_number) 
             over ( 
               PARTITION BY department) AS dep_empl_count 
    FROM   flattened_tree, 
           hr_org_unit_classifications_f houcf, 
           hr_all_organization_units_f haouf, 
           hr_organization_units_f_tl hauft, 
           per_all_assignments_m paam, 
           per_all_people_f papf 
    WHERE  haouf.organization_id = flattened_tree.department_id 
           AND haouf.organization_id = houcf.organization_id 
           AND haouf.organization_id = hauft.organization_id 
           AND haouf.effective_start_date BETWEEN 
               houcf.effective_start_date AND houcf.effective_end_date 
           AND hauft.LANGUAGE = 'US' 
           AND hauft.effective_start_date = haouf.effective_start_date 
           AND hauft.effective_end_date = haouf.effective_end_date 
           AND houcf.classification_code = 'DEPARTMENT' 
           AND Trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN hauft.effective_start_date AND 
                                      hauft.effective_end_date 
           AND hauft.organization_id = paam.organization_id 
           AND paam.person_id = papf.person_id 
           AND paam.primary_assignment_flag = 'Y' 
           AND paam.assignment_type = 'E' 
           AND paam.assignment_status_type IN ( 'ACTIVE', 'SUSPENDED' ) 
           AND paam.effective_latest_change = 'Y' 
           AND trunc(sysdate) between paam.effective_start_date and paam.effective_end_date
AND trunc(sysdate) between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date

ORDER  BY division,district,department
```

The output looks like -

```
DIVISION            DISTRICT        DEPARTMENT              JAN
CA Division         Grande          XYZ                     0
CA Division         Deer            Deer Tubing             1
CA Division         Deer            XYZ  Fracturing         0
CA Division         Fracturing      CAA  Fracturing         3

US Division         Neuquen         Support                 101
US Division         Neuquen         Cementing               3
US Division         Corporate       Fracturing              190
```

Now I want to calculate the sum in the same query at the division and district level. i.e. sum of headcounts(JAN Column) per district and per division in the same query. Is this possible ?

The output should look like -

```
DIVISION            DISTRICT        DEPARTMENT              JAN    SUM(DIVISION)    SUM(DISTRICT)
CA Division         Grande          XYZ                     0        4               0
CA Division         Deer            Deer Tubing             1        4               1
CA Division         Deer            XYZ  Fracturing         0        4               1
CA Division         Fracturing      CAA  Fracturing         3        4               3

US Division         Neuquen         Support                 101      294            104        
US Division         Neuquen         Cementing               3        294            104
US Division         Corporate       Fracturing              190      294            190
```

***so from above output- sum of division should be sum of all headcounts in one division (CA Division and US Division)
and sum of district should be for Deer district - 1+0=1    for Neuquen district 101+3=104 like that.***

Comment: Any reason you've not adopted the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax? They have been around for 28 years now. It's long past time you dropped that 31 year old syntax now.

Comment: edited the tag. Thanks !

Comment: @Larnu - Unfortunately thats the syntax we still use in our company. I will move to the new syntax soon hopefully !

Comment: I hope you never need to do a `LEFT JOIN` in your company then! I doubt Oracle supports the old `*=` syntax anymore, just like other modern RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu - Lol.. ! I will change my syntax.. I get the pun :D

Comment: @Larnu . . . They seem to have an aversion to `GROUP BY` as well . . . which I think has been in SQL since before there was a standard.

Comment: Poor soul probably came from a MySQL background @GordonLinoff ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff and @ Larnu - Thank you for the feedback ! I will change the syntax slowly and steadily. I am new to this forum and the SQL coding. Kindly forgive if I have unintentionally NOT used standard formatting !

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SHSH_123 . Sorry we derailed your question, but not using explicit joins (nor an explicit `GROUP BY`) is often seen as a red flag in the SQL community. It generally points to either a much larger design flaw or a significant lack of understand/knowledge of the language. Otherwise, it can be because someone is using a *very* old version an RDBMS, but then we're talking about versions released in the early 90's; so if you were using such a version and hadn't informed us then likely any answers would be useless to you as they would not be supported on decades old software.

Comment: @Larnu - Thanks for informing. I will take a note of it and maybe slowly change the syntax. I do know the use the new one but I will have to practice more with it to be hands on....

Comment: Any suggestion to the above question will be helpful !!! :D

Comment: Hard to answer such question without sample data. But it should be something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e3d24925cf4af03ce8755ecef11069f9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 1 measure:

```
   Count(DISTINCT person_number) 
     over ( 
       PARTITION BY department) AS dep_empl_count
```

Use 3 measures:

```
   Count(DISTINCT person_number) over (PARTITION BY department) AS dep_empl_count, 
   Count(DISTINCT person_number) over (PARTITION BY division) AS div_empl_count, 
   Count(DISTINCT person_number) over (PARTITION BY district) AS dis_empl_count
```